# How to drill down and show detail uitableview with splitview without storyboard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, xcode4

I implemented a splitview using 2 UITableViews and a UIViewController. Showing both on the screen with their own data is working fine.
Now in my DidSelectRowForIndexPath I did the following:

```
DetailViewController *nextController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
NSMutableArray *objects;
objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", nil];
nextController.title = @"Filter";
[nextController SetArray:objects];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextController];
[self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
//used this before [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
[FilterView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

1. Maybe you know a better method as what I did to present the nextController
2. The nextController is always showing up from the bottom and moving to the top. How can I accomplish this default sliding animation where the detail view comes into the view from the right side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to confirm that you have UINavigationController at base then you can pushViewController:nextController

```
[FilterView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
DetailViewController *nextController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
NSMutableArray *objects;
objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", nil];
nextController.title = @"Filter";
[nextController SetArray:objects];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

Comment: How can I make sure it's at base?

Comment: On window you have to have the UINavigationController. UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

// Configure and display the window.
[window addSubview:navController.view];

Comment: I added the NavController in window as you suggested. Then I have the navbar in all views but it still won' work. When I click on a row in lower view, the table does not drill down.

Answer (score 2):

If you have started the app from the master/detail template while creating the project. Then it will have the navigation controller set automatically in the appDelegate `didFinishLaunching` method so in the `didSelect` methods you have to just use

```
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`
```

instead of

`[self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];`

[Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58723521/SplitTableView.zip) is a sample code which uses split view with navigation to and from root view.

Comment: I was using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];` before but the view is not showing.

Comment: Yes I did, but it's an iPhone app and I still don't know why it's not working with `pushViewController`

Comment: then for iPhone app, how u r using split view... u made a custom one or using some ZUUIView..

Comment: I'm using a UIViewController, made it delegate for UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource and added to tableviews (with their corresponding sizes) to the View.